# Reusable function for a validation process

Tags: javascript, jquery

I previously asked how can I simplify a validation process:

[How can I simplify this JQuery validation process?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/244341/how-can-i-simplify-this-jquery-validation-process)

But in hindsight, what I really meant to ask was how can I turn that process into a reusable function.

I'm going through some old code that I wrote, and I am trying to clean it up so there's not a lot of redundant code.

I have many `onClick` events that look like this:

```
$('#addSubmit').on('click', function(){
  var addcriteria = {
    addcity: $('#addcity').val(),
    addregion: $('#addregion').val(),
    addloctype: $('#addloctype').val(),
    // several more values
  }

  if(addcriteria.addcity == "" || addcriteria.addcity == null){
    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    $('.message').text('You must enter a City.');       
    $('#errorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        document.forms["addEquipForm"].addcriteria.addcity.focus();
    });
    return false;       
  }
  if(addcriteria.addregion == ""){
    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    $('.message').text('You must select a Region.');        
    $('#errorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        document.forms["addEquipForm"].addcriteria.addregion.focus();
    });
    return false;       
  }
  // several more checks
  else{
    $.post('api/updateEquip.php', {addcriteria:addcriteria}, function(data){
        if(data == "Success"){
            $('#successModal').modal('show');
            $('.message').text('New Equipment has been added.');
            $('#successModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
                location.reload();
            });     
        }
        else{
            $('#errorModal').modal('show');
            $('.message').text('The Equipment could not be added.');        
            return false;                   
        }
    });
  }
});
```

As stated, I have many onClick events that look similar to the above.  I want to get better at creating custom functions, and I think this would be a good start.

This was my attempt at creating a custom reusable function for the above code...

I started by creating the function:

```
function criteriaCheck(checkCriteria){
  if(checkCriteria == ""){
    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
    $('.message').text('Error message of some sort.');      
    $('#errorModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        document.forms["addEquipForm"].checkCriteria.focus();
    });
    return false;   
  }
  else{
    // not sure what to return here
    // but I can console log a success message
    console.log('Success');
  }
}
```

Then, inside my `onClick` event, I can call the function and pass the value into the function:

```
var checkCriteria = '';

criteriaCheck(checkCriteria = addcriteria.addcity);
```

However, using these updates, I can only get "Success" in the console, even when I try to leave a blank form value.

With all of this said, how can I build a custom reusable function using the above `onClick` event?

Comment: Does this question meet the criteria for this board?  You’re passing a boolean into your function (`checkCriteria=addcriteria.addcity`), so your function is only receiving TRUE. Just pass the object itself.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea that I suggest is to decompose every bit of logic into small reusable functions. In my answer, I will touch only on validation logic because that part of your code has the most code duplication.

The following code is how I would like to see validation:

```
$('#addSubmit').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const validator = getValidator([
        [$('#addcity'), [
            combine(empty, emptyError),
            combine(notCapitalized, notCapitalizedError)]
        ],
        [$('#addregion'), [
            combine(emptyOrNull, emptyError)]
        ],
    ]);

    if (validator.hasErrors()) {
        const { element, error } = validator.getFirstError();
        $('.message').text(error.message);
        $('#errorModal').modal('show').on('hidden.bs.modal', element.focus.bind(element));
    } else {
        // Post request...
    }
});
```

Here we use the `validator` object to check if there are any errors and to get the first occurred error to display its message on the modal dialog. For the `getValidator` function we need to provide an element that we want to validate and a list of functions that find errors. Since functions that check for errors and actual errors are independent we need the ability to combine them. For example, the line `combine(empty, emptyError)` means that we want to check if a value is empty and return `emptyError` if so.

Also, I've made additional validation for the `city` field (see `notCapitalizedError`) to show how easy is to add new validation logic. To not hardcode error messages I've added `data-name=""` attributes to all inputs:

```
<input type="text" id="addcity" data-name="City" placeholder="City">
<input type="text" id="addregion" data-name="Region" placeholder="Region">
```

The implementation code is a bit hard to read and the following:

```
const empty = (str) => (str === "");
const emptyError = ($el) => ({ name: "empty", message: `You must enter a ${$el.data('name')}.` });
const notCapitalized = (str) => (!empty(str) && str[0] === str[0].toLowerCase());
const notCapitalizedError = ($el) => ({ name: "not-capitalized", message: `${$el.data('name')} should be capitalized.` });
const emptyOrNull = (val) => (empty(val) || val == null);


const combine = (hasError, createErr) => function($el) {
    return (hasError($el.val()) ? createErr($el) : null);
}

const getErrors = ($element, fns) => fns.map((fn) => fn($element)).filter(res => res !== null);
const getValidator = (data) => {
    const map = new Map();
    data.forEach(([$el, functions]) => {
        map.set($el, functions);
    })

    const elements = Array.from(map.keys());
    const getFunctions = ($el) => map.get($el) || [];
    const elErrors = ($el) => getErrors($el, getFunctions($el));
    const elHasErrors = ($el) => (elErrors($el).length > 0);
    const hasErrors = () => elements.some(elHasErrors);

    return {
        hasErrors,
        getFirstError: () => {
            if (hasErrors()) {
                const $element = elements.find(elHasErrors);
                return { element: $element, error: elErrors($element)[0]};
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I will test your suggestion asap and let you know if I am successful.